# MacPorts Freezes

Tags: macos, mac, macports

I just installed MacPorts. After that, I've been trying to install sqliteman. When the MacPorts reaches the gt4-mac package, it stay for two hours with this message:

> --->  Computing dependencies for sqliteman
>
> --->  Building qt4-mac

No message errors, no warnings. Is there a command to see if the building is really occurring?

Comment: It's not unusual for `qt4-mac` to take a few hours to build.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, guys. Saw in Activity Monitor that the gt4-mac build was working. To see better than that, I putted the -v (verbose) option in command line during install, like that:

```
sudo port -v install sqliteman
```

Now I can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Use top or the activity monitor app.  It's not unusual for qt4 to take hours to build though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run an http sniffer like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) while it's running to see what the requests and responses look like?

Also, have you watched your processes using ps or some other process monitor to see if it's actively doing anything?